Reactive Table in shadcn-svelte for every change in table row content (Edit the row and Delete the row)
I am building the web app using svelte and sveltekit.
And for UI i am using shadcn-svelte library.
I am using the exact same case like given in documentation such as call the DataTable component from +page.svelte
<DataTable {assessments} />
And in table i have did all same as documentation (same filtering, sorting, and actions)
    export let assessments: Template[];
    let table = createTable(readable(assessments), {
    filter: addTableFilter({
    fn: ({ filterValue, value }) => value.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase())
    }),
    });
    const columns = table.createColumns([
    table.column({ accessor: 'Title', header: 'Title' }),
    table.column({
    accessor: ({ id }) => id,
    header: '',
    cell: ({ value }) => {
    return createRender(DataTableActions, { id: value });
    },
    plugins: { sort: { disable: true }, filter: { exclude: true } }
    })
   ]);

in table action i am deleting the row as record using API call
    <script>
    async function handleDeleteAssessment(id: string) {
    const response = await Delete({ templateId: id });
    }
    async function Delete(model: { templateId: string }) {
    try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/server/assessment`, {
    method: 'DELETE',
    body: JSON.stringify(model),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
    return response;
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Delete Error:', error);
    return null;
    }
    }
    </script>
    
    <AlertDialog.Root>
    <AlertDialog.Trigger asChild let:builder>
    <Button builders={[builder]} variant="ghost" class="h-8 w-full justify-start">Delete</Button>
    </AlertDialog.Trigger>
    
    <AlertDialog.Title>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialog.Title>
    
    <AlertDialog.Action class="w-fit" on:click={() => handleDeleteAssessment(id)}>Continue</AlertDialog.Action>
    
    </AlertDialog.Root>

Being using reactivity wherever possible and invalidation table is not updating on deletion of record or i could say row is not reflecting dynamic changes on deletion.
Despite all data is reactive (Checked by loging on console)
